# How to print multiple record from same table in php

Tags: php, sql, database

I am new to php and developing website. I have one product page where many products are stored in database. When i print them all products come in single column, i did float:left but there is no change. But when i do the same thing entering manual products in html it is fine. Below is the code what i am using in php. Please help.

```
<div class="products-wrap">
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ProductName,Description,ProductImage FROM products");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo  "<div class='product-img'><img src='upload/".$row['ProductImage']."'/></div>";
  echo '<br/>';
  echo "<p>".$row['Description']."</p>"; 
  echo '<div class="product-details"><a href="#">Product Details</a></div>';
  }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
</div>
```

produst-wrap is the main div which have to print several times. there are 4 products in 1 row but when i use this coding all products show in single column.

Thanks

Comment: post your css also, please

Comment: You want multiple products on one line? Take out the <br/> - it forces a new line.

Comment: Actually i want to print products-wrap 4 times in a row. There is no error in css because when i do this just in html its fine.

Here are screenshots of both files from which you can understand well

http://www.naif-waleed.com/screenshot.jpg
http://www.naif-waleed.com/error.jpg

Comment: This definitely sounds like more of a css issue. Also, <div> is by default a block display in css, so you will need to set each div to display: inline; if you want in one row

Comment: @user2055788, please post your CSS here, and check my answer under if it can be that what you were missing.

Comment: Your code helps. Its working fine now. There was no css issue. But your code helps alot. Thanks Sergio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have in your example "makes all elements under each other" (as you say, and you posted no CSS for us to know otherwise). What I think you might be missing (so please try that) is to have the `<div class="products-wrap">` inside the `while` loop.

Like this:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ProductName,Description,ProductImage FROM products");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<div class='products-wrap'>";
echo "<div class='product-img'><img src='upload/".$row['ProductImage']."'/></div>";
echo '<br/>';
echo "<p>".$row['Description']."</p>"; 
echo '<div class="product-details"><a href="#">Product Details</a></div>';
echo '</div>';
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Let me know if this helped or was not what you are looking for.

Comment: Nice I could help. When you post in stackoverflow it's important to share as musch code as possible. And when you get the right answer, "accept it" as an answer by clicking on the accept button.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try iterate through a foreach loop

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT ProductName,Description,ProductImage FROM products");
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

foreach($rows as $row)
{
   echo "<div class='products-wrap'>";
   echo "<div class='product-img'><img src='upload/".$row['ProductImage']."'/></div>";
   echo '<br/>';
   echo "<p>".$row['Description']."</p>"; 
   echo '<div class="product-details"><a href="#">Product Details</a></div>';
   echo '</div>';
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: why is a `foreach` better than a `while`?

Comment: Personally I like to use foreach to iterate through results that are, or can be unknown, and use whiles for iterating through an array with the express purpose of finding, or triggering a specific flag . Not a huge difference, and probably didn't merit such a bland response, but I personally think it keeps code more semantic.